# Visual Studio Source Control Plugin Problem

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops, tfs, visual-studio-2019

I am using VS 2019 version 16.4.3 for customer projects.
There are two solutions with different source control systems. One of them uses git and the other uses TFS.

I am getting this warning message below sometimes. Looks like it is usually shown opening git solution after working with TFS solution.

[image: Source Control Plugin Warning]

When I check "Tools > Options > Source Control > Plug-in Selection > Current source control plug-in" setting in VS, I saw it is changed to "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server".

Then I am changing source control plugin for the git solution to the "Git" and deleting the created $tfs folder.

But sometime later it is happening again and changing source control plugin again and again.

Updating VS or changing version is not an option regarding to customer policies.

Is there anybody who knows any workarounds or how to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should add the `$tf` folder to your `.gitignore` file. (See [VisualStudio.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/main/VisualStudio.gitignore) in [github/gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore).) But besides getting into the habit of changing the 'Current source control plug-in' from 'Visual Studio Team Foundation Server' to 'git' before opening a solution or project from the git repo, I don't know of a way to prevent this message. (The behavior is the same in VS2022.)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanDodds I will try this, but do you know why this TFS folder is created?

Comment: The `$tf` folder is a cache for the TFVC workspace. (TFVC, or Team Foundation Version Control, is the 'native' legacy version control of TFS. The plug-in selection of "Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" is TFVC.)